# tcp tunnel inside local network with iptables and bridge involved

Tags: iptables, ip, port-forwarding

I want to configure outside and inside forwarding rules to behave the same way, and simplified problem that i have with 'inside part' is like this:

if i have

```
compA - eth0 192.168.0.1
compB - br0  192.168.0.2
        +eth0
compC - eth0 192.168.0.3     ...running appache on port80 with simple "it works" page
```

is it possible to make tcp tunnel in compB, that will forward port 80 from A to C.

When there is NO bridge (compB - eth0  192.168.0.2) enough commands are:

```
compB# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -d 192.168.0.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0 3
compB# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.0.3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j MASQUERADE
```

but after adding BRIDGE with commands:

```
compB# brctl addbr br0; brctl addif br0 eth0
compB# ip addr del 192.168.0.2/24 dev eth0
compB# ip addr add 192.168.0.2/24 dev br0
compB# ip route del default; ip route add default 192.168.0.2/24 dev br0
compB# ip link set dev br0 on
```

packets from compA do not reach compC anymore. Testing with:

```
compA# echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc 192.168.0.2 80
```

... which should return root http page of compC (working ok without bridge involved).

UPDATE:

SOLUTION1:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables
```

after disabling bridge hooks for iptables situation is OK again.
But I still looking for 'iptables commands combination' solution that will work with bridge configured standard way.

SOLUTION2:

```
ip link set dev br0 promisc on
```

works too, but will impact global performances.

SOLUTION3:

```
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ipv4 --ip-proto tcp --ip-dport 143 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ipv4 --ip-proto tcp --ip-dport  80 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -p ipv4 --ip-proto tcp --ip-sport  80 -j redirect --redirect-target DROP
```

... seems ok, info found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17116126/iptables-ebtables-bridge-utils-prerouting-forward-to-another-server-via-single) and [here](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Intercept/LinuxBridge).

Comment: Your last line is hard to follow.  You do want to forward and `iptables` does not care if you're dealing with a LAN, WAN or any type of network.  Try it with your current knowledge of `iptables` and if it doesn't work, show us what you did.

Comment: @JuliePelletier hm, you are right. this whole question is my mistake, it is related to my bridge inside compB... i will probably delete this question soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -d my.public.ip.address/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DNAT --to-destination a.different.ip.address:587
```

Note that `a.different.ip.address` could be on any interface as long as the routing table is properly configured.

You would also need the following to do the full loop:

```
iptables -A POSTROUTING -s a.different.ip.address/24 -j SNAT --to-source my.public.ip.address
```